# What is this handleChange method doing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleChange(e) {
        const index = Number(e.target.id.substring(e.target.id.length - 1, 19));
        const copyFormArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.educationData));
        copyFormArray[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            educationData: copyFormArray,
        });
    };
```

What does this handleChange method do, specifically in the index variable? I understand what substring and the Number constructor do but the second argument I cannot find any answers for this specific question although it works as intended.

Comment: By second argument, are you referring to `19`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi yes, the 19 in the substring method

Comment: That's the optional `indexEnd` parameter. Which according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is _The index of the first character to exclude from the returned substring._

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi In this case when the indexEnd is smaller than 10 it returns a typeerror that it cannot set the property of undefined, but when the indexEnd is excluded or > 10 it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring works in a tricky way, if second argument (in your case 19) is less than first argument - then they will be "swapped", and if not - it will just take text between indexes (argument1 and argument2).

So say for example i have a string:

```
var x = "aaaaa-5";
```

if i will write:

```
x.substring(x.length-1)
```

It will give me "5".

Then if i will write:

```
x.substring(3,6)
```

It will give me "aa-"

But then if i will write:

```
x.substring(6,3)
```

It will be exactly the same as previous call - "aa-"

So internally logic of substring is kind of like this:

```
function substring(start,end) {
 if(start > end) {
    var buf = end;
    end = start;
    start = buf;
 }
 //... other logic
}
```

Comment: I see, in this case when the indexEnd is smaller than 10 it returns a typeerror that it cannot set the property of undefined, but when the indexEnd is excluded or > 10 it works.

Comment: why 10? You mean 19? And you now go more specifically to logic and data that you have there, which i am not aware of

Comment: I was hacking with different numbers to try and understand why it is specifically 19. I was following a loose tutorial and the method wasn't explained so I'm trying to breakdown this part. Anyways appreciate it.

Comment: I guess in your case 19 should have been at the beginning (first argument), that's were confusion came from i guess